raster calculation custom function using multiple vrts
This is admittedly a long and involved question, so please bear with me. I am attempting to create a tree canopy mask for covering the State of Oregon using remotely-sensed data from the National Agricultural Imagery Project (NAIP).  To create this mask, I first calculated the normalized difference vegetation index from (NDVI) using the native 1ft resolution of the 4-band NAIP aerial imagery.  Next, I want to create a canopy height model (CHM) from the 3ft resolution NAIP digital aerial photogrammetry (DAP) digital surface model and a 10 meter National Elevation Dataset digital elevation model. Finally, I want to combine the CHM raster with the NDVI raster, and set any values where the CHM or the NDVI fail to meet the criteria that I am considering to be a tree.  I have worked out a function to make this work with fake data pretty simply:
##Loading Necessary Packages##
library(terra)
library(sf)
library(doParallel)

##Fake Data#
blank<-rast(ymin=45.5000, ymax=45.5010, xmin=-122.5010, xmax=-122.5000, nrow=1000, ncol=1000, crs="epsg:4326")
NDVI<-project(blank, y="epsg:2992")
values(NDVI)<-sample(seq(-10000, 10000, 1), ncell(NDVI), replace=TRUE)
DSM<-aggregate(NDVI, fact=c(3,3)) #to simulate the 3X coarser resolution of DSM compared to NDVI
DTM<-aggregate(DSM, fact=c(10,10)) #to simulate the 10X coarser resolution of DSM compared to NDVI
values(DTM)<-rnorm(ncell(DTM), 5000, 500)
DTM_3m<-resample(DTM, DSM)
values(DSM)<-values(DTM_3m) + sample(seq(0,250, 1), ncell(DSM), replace = TRUE)

##Creating the canopy mask
ndvi_3ft<-resample(NDVI, DSM)
dtm_3ft<-resample(DTM, DSM)
dsm_dtm<-c(DSM, dtm_3ft)
chm_3ft<-lapp(dsm_dtm, fun=function(X,Y){X-Y})
chm_ndvi<-c(chm_3ft, ndvi_3ft)
names(chm_ndvi)<-c("CanopyHeight", "NDVI")
out<-ifel(chm_ndvi$NDVI<2000|chm_ndvi$CanopyHeight<15, NA, chm_ndvi)

Now what is more complicated is figuring out how to make this work efficiently for a directory of DSM tiles, a directory of NDVI tile, and a directory of DTM tiles using virtual raster tables (VRTs).  From the fake data above, here are those vrts
##Create raster for tile extents
tilemask<-aggregate(DTM, fact=10) 

##Making directories for the tiles##
ndvi_dir<-file.path(tempdir(), "NDVI")
dsm_dir<-file.path(tempdir(), "DSM")
dtm_dir<-file.path(tempdir(), "DTM")

if(!dir.exists(ndvi_dir)){
  dir.create(ndvi_dir)
}

if(!dir.exists(dsm_dir)){
  dir.create(dsm_dir)
}

if(!dir.exists(dtm_dir)){
  dir.create(dtm_dir)
}

##Making the tiles and writing them to disk
makeTiles(NDVI, tilemask, filename=paste(ndvi_dir, "ndvi_.tif", sep="/"))
makeTiles(DSM, tilemask, filename=paste(dsm_dir, "dsm_.tif", sep="/"))
makeTiles(DTM, tilemask, filename=paste(dtm_dir, "dtm_.tif", sep="/"))

##Reading in the file paths of the tiles##
ndvi_tiles<-list.files(ndvi_dir, pattern="*.tif$", full.names=TRUE)
dsm_tiles<-list.files(dsm_dir, pattern="*.tif$", full.names=TRUE)
dtm_tiles<-list.files(dtm_dir, pattern="*.tif$", full.names=TRUE)

##Creating VRTs of the tiles##
vrt(ndvi_tiles, file.path(ndvi_dir, "NDVI_vrt.vrt"), overwrite=TRUE)
vrt(dsm_tiles, file.path(dsm_dir, "DSM_vrt.vrt"), overwrite=TRUE)
vrt(dtm_tiles, file.path(dtm_dir, "DTM_vrt.vrt"), overwrite=TRUE)

I asked this previous question for an earlier phase of this project. @RobertHijmans helped me create a custom function in parallel in a memory safe way with by passing filenames to the workers.  I have emulated that same structure for the tree mask calculation.  While the below code will work to produce the desired result, it is painfully slow because I have to crop the vrts for NDVI and DTM to align with the DSM raster tile in each iteration.
##Function for the canopy mask##
canopy_fxn<-function(NDVI, DSM, DTM, outpath){
  DSM<-rast(DSM)
  ndvi<-rast(NDVI)
  dtm<-rast(DTM)
  out<-file.path(outpath, basename(sources(DSM)))
  if(!file.exists(out)){
    ndvi_tmp<-crop(ndvi, DSM)
    ndvi_3ft<-resample(ndvi_tmp, DSM)
    dtm_tmp<-crop(dtm, DSM)
    dtm_3ft<-resample(dtm_temp, DSM)
    dsm_dtm<-c(DSM, dtm_3ft)
    chm_3ft<-lapp(dsm_dtm, fun=function(X,Y){X-Y})
    chm_ndvi<-c(chm_3ft, ndvi_3ft)
    names(chm_ndvi)<-c("CanopyHeight", "NDVI")
    ifel(chm_ndvi$NDVI<2000|chm_ndvi$CanopyHeight<15, NA, chm_ndvi, filename=out, wopt=list(datatype="INT4S"), overwrite=TRUE)
rm(ndvi_tmp, dsm_tmp, dsm_3ft, dtm_3ft, chm_3ft, chm_ndvi, ndvi_3ft)
}
return(out)
rm(DSM, out) 
}

##Getting the list of DSM tiles to use for iterations## 
dsm_list<-vrt_tiles(rast(file.path(dsm_dir, "DSM_vrt.vrt")))

outpath<-file.path(tempdir(), "Canopy")

if(!dir.exists(outpath)){
dir.create(outpath)
}
##Preparing for parallel processing  
ncores<-detectCores()-1
clust<-makeCluster(ncores)
registerDoParallel(clust)

#Running canopy height mask function in parallel##
foreach(i = dsm_list) %dopar%{
 canopy_fxn(NDVI=file.path(ndvi_dir, "NDVI_vrt.vrt"), DSM=i, DTM=file.path(dtm_dir, "DTM_vrt.vrt"), outpath=outpath) 
 gc()  
}

##stop parallel processing
stopCluster(clust)

##delete the files##
unlink(ndvi_dir, recursive=TRUE)
unlink(dsm_dir, recursive=TRUE)
unlink(dtm_dir, recursive=TRUE)
unlink(outpath, recursive=TRUE)

Is there a way I can leverage the spatial indexing created by the VRTs to read in just the NDVI and DTM tiles necessary to perform each iteration of the canopy mask function?  Any help would be much appreciated.

Admittedly I haven't followed the full trajectory here, but (assuming all members dsm, nvdi, dtm, had same extent prior to tiling), makeTile filename alters each filename by adding tile number, which should be the same tile number for each member: dsm, nvdi, dtm. This also assumes the 'aggregations' above brought all members to same resolution prior to tiling. So, a regex perhaps as index? But, as noted, I haven't really followed the full path here. isn't tiling also cropping, thus crop already done? And I've likely missed the point altogether.

@Chris, that is a good point, and isolated to my reprex, that could potentially work.  I made the tiling scheme the same in the reprex just for convenience, but for the actual datasets I am using, the tiling schemes differ between the three datasets.  So you are correct that the tiling crops, but because of how my actual data are tiled there will likely be multiple ndvi tiles in each dsm tile and multiple dsm tiles in each dtm tile.

Unfortunate. Would median or mean of the multiples be complete nonsense, or some other approach to best fit among the many? You might also look at how collapse pkg might come into play (for speed - though terra is seemingly as fast and memory efficient as it can be), vignette('collapse_and_sf' and vignette('collapse_intro', might lead to voila, collapse_terra. Or, re-tile if you have control of that end of the pipeline.

For what I am after, summarizing is not desirable, but you just gave me an idea.  I might be able to simply read in the extents of the raster tiles first, and use sf_intersects() to determine which ndvi and dtm tiles actually intersect the dsm tile of interest, and just read in those rasters.

Not sf_intersects() as that will catch relations not aligned at origin (of tile), but... ==, kinda 'all_equal', so sf_contains_properly(), or perhaps more simply st_equals.

I think this may not have been an R issue at all.  At some point to prevent a memory overload on my windows system, I had set up a paging file on the C;/ Drive.  Then a colleague advised me to try using forked parallel process in a window subsystem for linux.  I got rid of the paging file, and now it is working perfectly with the code I originally had - even with the crop()

Best practices suggests now answering your own question and accepting, by documenting the process and solutions arrived at, as this will help others, and answered questions are explored first. Been interesting to ponder, thanks.
